# permissions to access linkedin's users profile

Tags: linkedin-api

*I have tried to access #linkedIn's users profile* using the links-https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName) and https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me both but got the error-

**{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me",
"status": 403
}**

I have client id, secret id and able to generate authorization code and access token using the Apis for that I am following this doc-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=HTTPS  for step4, I am unable to access #linkedIn's users profile.
If need permissions, please  **#linkedIn community** give me the same and for further contact, **DM** me on this **email-id - vkg6614@gmail.com** . I want to access the users profile for https://upskilltalent.com/ this company

for better understanding please go through this doc--
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=HTTPS

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin%2Fmarketing%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-08

I would assume you're not requesting enough scopes when requesting the access token from LinkedIn.

You probably need `r_basicprofile` or `r_liteprofile`